# Weird bug with iPhone 6+ 8.2 simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, simulator, iphone-6-plus

I am experiencing a weird bug with the iPhone 6+ simulator. When I am on version 8.1 certain image look blurry (does not have the @3x image), but on simulator 8.2 (does not have @3x image as well), but it doesn't look blurry at all. Has anyone else experience this. I got @3x images anyways now. Just need to know if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: What is the exact name of your image?

Comment: The resolution of your screen must be lower than the resolution of iPhone 6+, so it seems to be fine in the simulator, but actually it isn't, you can't just realise.